# The import android.media.audiofx cannot be resolved

Tags: android

I want to import Equalizer and Visualizer in my application as i saw here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/audiofx/Equalizer.html but I get this : The import android.media.audiofx cannot be resolved. Is the problem in build sdk version?

```
  <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8">
```

-

```
 private Visualizer mVisualizer;
        private Equalizer mEqualizer;
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion=">
```

To:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="9">
```

The classes you want were only added in API 9. If they are an integral part of your app, you should change your minSdkVersion to 9 as well, or add runtime checks to make sure you're running on API 9 or higher.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to change project.properties as well